# JSSOR - How to make transition slide left

Tags: jquery, jssor

I would like to know how to make my slides have a sliding transition to the left just like when I click and drag it. At the moment the transitions are random (zooming, breaking apart, etc). I am using the slider that is featured on the http://www.jssor.com/ homepage.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I found pieces of code on the JSSOR website but I don't know where to use the code. This code makes it slide right: {$Duration:400,$FlyDirection:1,$Easing:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad}

Answer (score 1):

**Slide right:**
{$Duration:400,x:-1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}

**Slide left:**
{$Duration:400,x:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}

You can try all avaliable transitions for this plugin here:

http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

They have a great sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

See

```
//from left to right
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:400,$FlyDirection:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}];
//from right to left
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:400,$FlyDirection:2,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}];
```

Btw, $FlyDirection is obsolete, please use 'x' instead.

```
//from left to right
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:400,x:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}];
//from right to left
var _SlideshowTransitions = [{$Duration:400,x:-1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InQuad}];
```

Comment: It should work, please try the first transition and then try the second.